# On Load Testing in Visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, testing, load

I have one web service and Unit test project, Service is deployed at client site and I have code of unit test Project.

I have to perform web performance and load test on web service using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Maybe provide more information or what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi Drmariod, I have to check the performance of Web service using Visual Studio 2013, Web service is already deployed on Client location. How can I perform load test on that service, I had gone through msdn but not getting clear idea of Test Controllers and Agents...

Comment: Till now I had tried to perform performance Testing of web Srvice and then tried to perform Load test on the same, But in local.testings file I had defined My LOCAL m/c setting, so o/p is showing result of my m/c. (example processor time, Agent/controller name). I want to get o/p of remote m/c which shows No. of agents currently consuming that service....

Comment: Please do not use all those abbreviations (eg "m/c" "o/p) and also [edit] the question to add the extra information. Also, please read [mcve] and the help pages about how to write good questions here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I thinks that's enough to describe my problem... I had already mentioned the steps which I had followed....  m/c is abbreviation for machine and o/p is abbreviation for output and that's the general words for any technical guy...